# What is this error while running emulator "java.lang.RuntimeException command faileds with symbian error code -30472"?

Tags: java-me, symbian, nokia, mobile-emulator

I am running J2ME project on **"S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v0.9"** emulator but while running the emulator I found the above error. Searching on the google I found that NOKIA has not given the specification for this error code. Can anybody solve this? Also, can I run this project directly on the device itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-30472 is an error from the Software Installer indicating that your installation file is corrupted ([source](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?149596-Symbian-error-code-30471/page2)). Perhaps your Midlet JAR isn't packaged correctly?